# Get Single Value in foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.6

I am using json_encode on foreach its return multiple values i want only one value after foreach completed

```
 foreach($tree as $file) {
 $arr = array('success'=>'ok');
 echo json_encode($arr);
 }

{"success":"ok"}{"success":"ok"}{"success":"ok"}{"success":"ok"}{"success":"ok"}{"success":"ok"}
```

Expected Output

```
{"success":"ok"}
```

Comment: print this `echo json_encode($arr);` array outside of foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

Do like following:

```
foreach($tree as $file) {
 $arr = array('success'=>'ok');
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

**Output will be as expected:** `{"success":"ok"}`

Comment: i am using ajax call on the function.  function run multiple time when multiple success response will be show

Comment: Could you please share your full script of PHP and ajax call?

Comment: `jQuery("#form-submit").click(function(e){
  var name = 'ragu';
  $j.ajax({ 
   type: 'post',
   url:ajaxurl,
   data: {
    action:"my_ajax_function",
    name:name
   },
   success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);

   // $j("#message").html("<b>File Uploaded Successfully</b>");
    // console.log(url);
    // console.log(data); //should print out the name since you sent it along
    // location. reload(true);
   },
   error: function(errorThrown){
    // console.log(errorThrown);
    // location. reload(true);
   } 
  });
 });`

Comment: `function data(){
foreach($tree as $file) {
 $arr = array('success'=>'ok');
}
echo json_encode($arr);
}`

Comment: multiple time call data()  its return

Comment: Please update in your question to better view of it.

Comment: I thought if you follow my answer then whenever you hit your submit button its throw only one success response in your ajax success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181192/discussion-between-raghbendra-nayak-and-ragupathi).